# A MONGODB query that works in STUDIO 3T but doesnt on Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a query that works in STUDIO 3t but the same query doesnt fetch any data in express js.

The code is here

studio 3t query

```
db.getCollection("tickets").find({
    $and: [
        {"TCKT_CRTE_DTTM" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2018-04-22"}, 
                                      "$lte": {"$date" : "2019-04-23"}}  },
          { "TRBL_TCKT_NUM": 2 }
    ]
});
```

Express code :-

```
tktRouter.get('/ticketsearch', (req,res) => {


    db.mongo.collection('tickets').find({
        $and: [
            {"TCKT_CRTE_DTTM" : { $gte : { $date : "2018-04-22" }, $lte: {$date : "2019-04-23" }}  },
            { "TRBL_TCKT_NUM": 2 }
        ]
    }).toArray(function(err, data) {
        if(err){

            res.json({ "error": "Tickets data not found." });
        } else{
            res.json({
                message: "success",
                data
            })
        }
    })

 });
```

Right now im just getting the message:"success", data: []
but on studio 3t it lists all the values.

Answer (score 0):

The queries done in MONGODB doesnt work in EXPRESS, you have to make some changes.